# In VB.net 2015, when I try to title the message box, the foolowing crash occurs:

Tags: vb.net

My original code as follows:

```
    If Not Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) And Not Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) Then

        e.Handled = True
        MsgBox(("Radius of the Traingle should be numeric value"), "Error!")
    End If
```

`Crash: Additional information: Conversion from string "Error!" to type 'Integer' is not valid.`

Comment: Dont ignore the help that intellisense offers as you type method parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace you MsgBox with the following code:

```
    MsgBox("Radius of the triangle ...", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error!")
```